# How to prove a function is onto?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I know the basic concept of onto but I just don't get how do you prove is onto. I know that the range = co-domain for it to be onto but I just don't understand the proofs given.

For example how would one prove that the following functions are onto:

1. $g(x) = x + 4$
2. $h(x) = -x$
3. $i(x) = x-4$

Comment: Onto what exactly? Is the codomain $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All the functions are bijective, regardless.

Comment: @EdwardJiang Not neccesarily: consider the first one as a function $g: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$. There is nothing in the domain that maps to the interval $[0,4)$, so it is not onto.

Comment: Well, sure. I assume it's going to be a more "natural" set, such as the integers, or the rationals.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ you could use the horizontal line test. I think graphical representation of functions are nice for questions of 'onto'. For a very easy example, F(x)=x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't prove that a function only defined by $g(x)=x+4$ is onto if you don't know the domain or co-domain.

Given sets $A$ and $B$, you can say a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is "onto" (as in "$f$ is a function from $A$ *onto* $B$") if for all $y \in B$, there exists an $x$ in $A$ such that $f(x)=y$.

If your function $g$ is defined as $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=x+4$, *then* you can say $g$ is onto because given any $y\in \mathbb{R}$, you can set $x=y-4$ to get$$g(x)=g(y-4)=y$$

Comment: Right you are. In this context, a function is *never* satisfactorily described by a formula alone: the domain and the target space (codomain) *must* be mentioned in the naming or description of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the functions are $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:

The basic idea is to find an element in the domain that maps to every element in the range, like this:

For the first one, take any $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $g(y-4) = y$, and since $y - 4 \in \mathbb{R}$,  $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, the function is onto.

Do you think you can do the rest of them?